# EASYPAISA/JAZZCASH Payment Integration method (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, payment-gateway

Here is the issue and I am not able to find anything. I am not able to understand how can I do it because I have never done this before.
I want to integrate payment api(easypaisa/jazzcash) into my grocery app.
I don't find any help(neither youtube tutorial not anything else)

Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks and Regards
Farah Jabeen

Answer (score 0):

you can use webview in Android and use REST API for integration. OR
you can use Jazzcash mobile SDK for integration. API and Mobile SDK is available on jazzCash sandbox portal.

Comment: It's really help me. Thank you. Waiting for next part